# Pegar Restante dos Registros

Tags: mysql

Tem uma função no ORM do Laravel que faz o `LIMIT` do **MySQL**.

Que é o `Take` e o `Skip`.

Vou fazer três Owl Slider na página, um debaixo do outro. E as imagens que vou colocar vem de uma tabela na base de dados. Quero que nos três carrosséis tenham a mesma quantidade de imagens.

Então eu pensei em fazer assim:

```
Total de Registros / 3
```

Mas isso pode ocorrer uma dízima, por exemplo:

```
10 / 3 = 3,3333333333333333
```

Mas para resolver isso faço um `floor` no PHP e ele arredonda para 3.

Daí ficaria 3 em uma linha, 3 em outra e 3 em outra. Mas faltou uma imagem que eu quero que apareça na última linha.

A lógica seria:

```
$result = floor($countWorks / 3);

$slider_1 = Works::take($result)->get();
$slider_2 = Works::take($result)->skip($result)->get();
$slider_3 = Works::take($result)->skip($result + $result)->get();
```

Eu só quero saber o seguinte:

1 - Tem outro jeito de fazer isso ou esse é o melhor jeito ?

O Owl Slider funciona assim:

```
<?php 
    $works = R::find('works', 'status = 1');
    $take  = array_chunk($works, 3);

    foreach($take as $work){
?>
    <div class="owl-slider-works">
        <?php 
            foreach($work as $val){
        ?>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/works/<?=$val->capa?>" alt="<?=$val->titulo?>">
                <div class="titulo">
                    <h5><?=$val->titulo?></h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php 
            }
        ?>
    </div>
<?php 
    }
?>
```

Precisa ficar dessa forma dentro do `foreach`. Mas não entendo como o `chunk` vai funcionar para fazer isso. Como seria ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Zoom, essa fica fácil se você utilizar as funcionalidades da `Collection` do `Laravel`.

Vamos lá. Primeiro você seleciona todos os dados.

```
 $slider = Works::all();
```

Depois, você pode usar o método `Illuminate\Support\Collection::chunk` para "quebrar" os resultados em pedaços específicos. Nesse caso, vamos quebrar de 3 em 3. Se tiver alguma "sobra", o PHP deixará no último Collection (o chunk cria outros collections)

```
  @foreach( $slider->chunk(3) as $chunk)
      <div class="owl-slider">
       @foreach($chunk as $slide)
           <div class="item">{{ $slide->image }}</div>
        @endforeach
      </div>
  @endforeach
```

Pare entender melhor o `chunk`, vamos exemplificar com a função `array_chunk` do PHP (que é usada internamente pela Collection):

```
 $nomes = ['zoom', 'rray', 'wallacemaxters', 'bigown', 'randrade'];

 $de_2_em_2 = array_chunk($nomes, 2);

 print_r($de_2_em_2);
```

O resultado disso será:

```
[
   ["zoom", "rray",],
   ["wallacemaxters", "bigown",],
   ["randrade",],
]
```

Observe que no final o valor `"randrade"` ficou sozinho, porque como não houve 2 valores para combinar, então o último grupo fica contendo somente o resto.

Comment: Que interessante. Não sabia desse método `chunk`. Mas deixa eu perguntar uma coisa... vou editar a minha pergunta.

Comment: não está funcionando. Coloquei 10 fotos... e ele imprimiu 4 linhas, 3 linhas com 3 fotos e 1 linha com 1... ou seja, 4 linhas. Eu quero que apareça apenas 3 linhas e o resto... ou seja 4, 4 e 2... Rsrsrs

Comment: Actualizei o código do meu poste...

Comment: Deve ser algo errado no meu foreach

Comment: Resolvi! Eu te falei ontem que eu tinha que pegar o total e dividir por três... e você falou "Não não... filho, o chunk faz isso sozinho... nhenhenhe"... daí eu dei um ceil e boa.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda